# How to delete several values in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know how to delete a set of rows with a statements like these:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id=23 AND year=2012 AND value=16
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id=17 AND year=2012 AND value=16
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id=64 AND year=2012 AND value=16
```

But I would like to combine the above three statements into a single DELETE where id is either 23, 17, or 64.

What is the syntax for doing this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the SQL `IN` keyword.  For example:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN (23, 17, 64) AND year=2012 AND value=16
```

*Note:* Oracle has a limit of 1,000 items in a list.

Answer (score 5):

```
DELETE FROM my_table 
WHERE id in (17, 23, 64) AND year=2012 AND value=16
```

Answer (score 3):

You can chain the `AND/OR` conditions to achieve the same effect. In this case, a simple `IN` would solve your purpose.

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id IN (23, 17, 64) AND year=2012 AND value=16
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE (id=23 or id=17 or id=64) AND year=2012 AND value=16
```