# SQLite DELETE several records with specified composite primary keys

Tags: qt, sqlite

My table contains 2 INTEGER primary key columns. I would like to delete several records with both of them specified. For example, (1,1) and (1,2). I've tried:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE(primarykey1,primarykey2) IN ((1,1),(1,2))
```

incorrect syntax.

Comment: It's probably easier to use two different delete statements. Either way, SQLite does not have "tuples", so `(primarykey1,primarykey2)` is not an expression.

Comment: What if there are 2000 delete statements? Two - was just an example.

Comment: In code, you can prepare a delete statement with query parameters for whatever key you're deleting, then bind different values to those parameters in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to SQLite... I use Qt. Can you show some example code as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE primarykey1 = 1 AND primarykey2 IN (1,2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since SQLite version 3.15, you can use the following syntax:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE (p1, pk2) IN (VALUES(1,1),(1,2));
```

Comment: Haha :) I've googled using keywords in your answer and I got one :)

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691483/how-to-delete-several-values-in-sql)